# Delphi convert csv to utf-8

Tags: delphi

I have a csv file which might or might not be in utf-8 format.

Is there a way to convert an existing .csv to utf-8 format and then just overwrite the existing one?

Comment: Well isn't utf8 backward comparable with ascii? There's no "converting" needed if that's the only two encoding you're dealing with.

Comment: Who's to say the CSV isn't already UTF-8 encoded? I don't recall commas ever indicating anything about their encoding scheme :P

Comment: So is there a way to check of a csv is in utf-8 in delphi?

Comment: UTF-8 has a "byte order mark" (misnomer, since obviously there's no byte-order) at the beginning of the file. If you see 3 gibberish characters (`ï»¿`) (or three bytes: **0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF**) when opening the file as ANSI encoded, you know it's UTF-8.

Comment: UTF8 may or may not include a BOM, @Andon

Comment: What is your question. How to detect whether or not a file is UTF8

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True, but short of that, if there are no characters that exist outside the standard ANSI codepage in the .csv, it is equally plausible the software spit out a UTF-8 encoded file as it is ANSI :-\

Comment: Thanks...I'll do some research on that

Comment: See [Detecting 'text' file type (ANSI vs UTF-8)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4907942/576719).

Comment: @Andon Correct, it is impossible to know what the encoding is if all you have is the content of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV is a way of organising characters in a file, placing meaning on certain characters in terms of the structure of the file.

UTF8 is a way of encoding the characters stored in the file.

Talking about "converting CSV to UTF8" is like talking about "converting blue to loud".  A file format is not a file encoding any more than a colour is a measure of volume.

It sounds as if your real problem is how to determine whether a file is UTF8 encoded or not (and if not, what encoding *is* involved).  Which has nothing to do with Delphi (unless and until you come across problems with any specific Delphi implementation attempting to achieve this)

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Kudos on a very clear explanation.